# Reading file in java produces wrong characters

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, readfile

I'm currently doing the Coursera Bioinformatics specialization and I'm stuck at the **Reverse Complement Problem**. I'm not asking for an answer to this problem, because this would be unethical.

When I test my solution with a test dataset which I put as a String directly in the sourcecode, my answer is correct. But when I test my solution with a dataset which I read from a text-file, I get a wrong answer. A dataset consists of random characters (A, T, C, G).

My main-method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String dataset = readFile("filepath/dataset_3_2 (7).txt");
    String output = reverseComplement(dataset);
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("ergebnis.txt"));
        writer.write(output);

    }
    catch ( IOException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if ( writer != null)
            writer.close( );
        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    System.out.println(checkForWrongCharacters(dataset));
    System.out.println("Invalid characters: " + returnOthers(dataset));
}
```

Since the input dataset should only contain the letters A, G, C, T. Therefore I have implemented two methods to check for invalid characters.

```
public static String returnOthers(String pattern)
{
    StringBuilder others = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = pattern.charAt(i);
        switch(c) {
        case 'A': continue;
        case 'G': continue;
        case 'T': continue;
        case 'C': continue;
        default: others.append(c);
        break;
        }
    }
    return others.toString();
}
```

This is the other one:

```
public static boolean checkForWrongCharacters(String pattern)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++)
    {
        String s = "";
        char c = pattern.charAt(i);
        switch(c) {
        case 'A': continue;
        case 'G': continue;
        case 'T': continue;
        case 'C': continue;
        default: s = "Z";
        break;
        }
        result.append(s);
    }
    if(result.toString().contains("Z"))
    {
        flag = true;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The method `checkForWrongCharacters()` return true, which means there are charakters in the dataset which are not A, T, C or G. But the method `returnOthers()` doesen't return anything.

Is it possible that there is some encoding problem when I read huge text-files?

**EDIT**

Totally forgot to post my `readFile()` method...

```
public static String readFile(String filename) throws IOException
{
    String content = null;
    File file = new File(filename);
    FileReader reader = null;
    try {
         reader = new FileReader(file);
         char[] chars = new char[(int) file.length()];
         reader.read(chars);
         content = new String(chars);
         reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(reader !=null){reader.close();}
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: What does your readFile method look like?

Comment: Can you print the content that's returned from readFile() for debug purpose?

Comment: I'm not able to print the content of the String dataset (which contains the contents of the file which is read with the method readFile()) propably because content is too large. The file contains 8925 characters. When I try to print it, there is nothing printed.

Comment: In debug mode I can see that dataset contains the String of the text-file that is read, but I can't check the whole String because it's 8925 characters long.

Comment: I found the error. There's a carriage return (\r) being put into the String dataset.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This did the job.  There were carriage returns and newlines that messed up the result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String dataset = readFile("filepath/dataset_3_2 (7).txt");
    String dataset1 = dataset.replace("\r","");
    String dataset2 = dataset1.replace("\n","");
    String output = reverseComplement(dataset2);
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("ergebnis.txt"));
        writer.write(output);

    }
    catch ( IOException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if ( writer != null)
            writer.close( );
        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    System.out.println(checkForWrongCharacters(dataset));
    System.out.println("Invalid characters: " + returnOthers(dataset));
}
```

Comment: This way you end up with four separate copies of the data. You should at least reuse the same variable for all the `replace()` results. But if the file consists of lines it would have been much simpler to read it with `readLine()` in the first place.